# element moves left on hide

Tags: jquery, css

I'm displaying an error message in the middle of the screen, then after a few seconds it will fade out.

This works, but what I don't want happening is the error message moving to the far left of the screen when fading out.

I'm not sure if this is being cause because of css or the actual jquery itself.

Here's an example of what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/dLt51xwe/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $('#error').html("<div class='error-message'>ERROR</div>").show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#error').hide("slow");
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

I was wondering if it was the margin on the css that was causing it, so I tried this instead:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
width: 40%;
position: relative;
```

But I still got the same problem where the element would move to the far left while fading out.

I've also tried using the fadeOut() option provided, but the fading doesn't work. The fadeOut() seems to only work in an event for me, and I'm using this in an else statement.

Example out of an event: http://jsfiddle.net/dLt51xwe/1/

Any help is greatly appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't contain an else statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.fadeOut("slow")` instead of `.hide("slow")` the issue is to do with the default easing on [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/). I've always found it hard to find the available strings to use for the easing option - so its simpler to use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $('#error').html("<div class='error-message'>ERROR</div>").show();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#error').fadeOut("slow");
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

---

**in response to  ItsMatt's comment**

See your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/dLt51xwe/2/

`fadeOut()` and `hide()` wasn't working on the `<errormessage>` element you created, so instead I edited the javascript to call `fadeOut()` on the internal div `.error-message` rather than the `<errormessage>` container element.

See here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('errormessage').html("<div class='error-message'>Please enter a valid message!</div>").show();
  setTimeout(function () {
      $('.error-message').fadeOut("slow");
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: This works, but one thing I forgot to mention was that I'm not using this with an event, and the fadeOut just instantly hides. My error message is being run in an else statement. http://jsfiddle.net/dLt51xwe/1/

Comment: Ahhh.. Thank you! I just thought of it.. The html was getting overridden when showing the error, so after that the element wasn't present any more.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use jQuery function `fadeOut()` will solve the problem:

Change

```
$('#error').hide("slow");
```

to

```
$('#error').fadeOut("slow");
```